# How to compare all elements of a list with each other?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

How can I do this in a Java lambda stream, avoiding duplicates?

```java
List<SubItem> tempSplitFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
List<SubItem> splitFilesList = new ArrayList<>();

for (SubItem item1 : tempSplitFilesList) {
    for (SubItem item2 : tempSplitFilesList) {
        if (item1.getStop().equals(item2.getStart())) {
            splitFilesList.add(item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  But I wouldn't say it is better than what you have.  And what you have also contains duplicates as does this.

```
List<SubItem> splitFilesList = tempSplitFilesList.stream()
        .flatMap(item1 -> tempSplitFilesList.stream()
                .filter(item2 -> item1.getStop()
                        .equals(item2.getStart()))) // .distinct() if no dups
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates you can put a `.distinct()` method call after the filter.  This will work since equals, even by default, will return true if the same objects are compared.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can swap the inner and outer loop (or *`stream`*) and use [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) methods:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SubItem> list = List.of(
            new SubItem("123", "111"),
            new SubItem("234", "222"),
            new SubItem("345", "333"),
            new SubItem("456", "444"),
            new SubItem("567", "123"),
            new SubItem("678", "234"),
            new SubItem("789", "345"));

    List<SubItem> list2 = list.stream()
            .filter(item1 -> list.stream()
                    .anyMatch(item2 -> item1.getStart()
                            .equals(item2.getStop())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // output
    list2.forEach(System.out::println);
    //SubItem{start='123', stop='111'}
    //SubItem{start='234', stop='222'}
    //SubItem{start='345', stop='333'}
}
```

```java
public static class SubItem {
    String start, stop;

    public SubItem(String start, String stop) {
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    public String getStart() { return start; }
    public String getStop() { return stop; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubItem{start='" + start + "', stop='" + stop + "'}";
    }
}
```